# shiny downloadHandler timeout

Tags: r, shiny

I have produced a shiny application that requires a download that takes longer than the time that download handler allows. I keep getting an error that says "NO DATA RECIEVED" before the data that I am downloading has completed.

Is there any way to increase the length of the timeout of downloadHandler in Shiny Server Applications?

Answer (score 2):

The default timeout for the connection is 45 s. This can be increased by setting the http_keepalive_timeout in the shiny server configuration file. Have a look here:
https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/blob/master/config/shiny-server-rules.config