# Updating Shiny Server Config to change timeout error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny app with a `downloadHandler` built in and it works great for smaller datasets but when the file gets large (330 MB), it times out and I get an error.

I found this SO question ([shiny downloadHandler timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513329/shiny-downloadhandler-timeout)) which seems to address the answer although I don't know how to update the config file to take into account `http_keepalive_timeout`.

Below is my config file:

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;


# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed it using this SO answer [User session is getting interrupted after approx. 45 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45300285/user-session-is-getting-interrupted-after-approx-45-seconds)

I was putting the `http_keepalive_timeout` function in the wrong place. Please see below for the correct `shiny-server.conf` update:

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;
http_keepalive_timeout 180;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;

  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, same problem... are you using shiny-server pro or open source version?

Comment: Using the open source version. Make sure you are putting the function in the right section of the configuration file.